# ScaleType in ImageView not working

Tags: android, imageview, android-volley, networkimageview, scaletype

I am trying to make a gallery of images using ViewPager and Volley's NetworkImageView. Everything is working fine with the viewpager and image retrieve. But when i put the bitmap in the NetworkImageView, the image is not stretched to fill the size of the NetworkImageView. With my other ImageView, setting the scaleType works just fine.

```
<com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" />
```

My xml file

```
public static class SwipeFragment extends Fragment {

    ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View swipeView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.swipe_fragment, container, false);
        NetworkImageView imageView = (NetworkImageView) swipeView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        int position = bundle.getInt("position");
        if (imageLoader == null) {
            imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
        }
        imageView.setImageUrl(fotoUrl.get(position), imageLoader);
        return swipeView;

    }

    static SwipeFragment newInstance(int position) {
        SwipeFragment swipeFragment = new SwipeFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt("position", position);
        swipeFragment.setArguments(bundle);
        return swipeFragment;
    }
}
```

My java

Any idea about this problem?
I have also tried to change the scaleType into fitCenter but still the same results. Thank you in advance.

Comment: This applies to all ImageView that with wrap_content width and height scaling doesn't apply. Not specific to Volley's ImageView.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your issue is because of the wrap_content values used for width and height. Try to use the below code and it should work.

```
<com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" />
```

> When you say wrap_content that means you are asking view to be of same
>   height and width of the image hence scaling doesn't apply. When you
>   fix the width and height then you can apply fitXY scale type.